# How to query authors by custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, users, user-meta, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I have a custom taxonomy for users which is country.
Is there a way to query all admins by term_id or should I get all users and check each one with a for loop?

I tried this:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array (  'role' => 'administrator',  'tax_query' => array(array('taxonomy' => 'country', 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => $country_id ) )  ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would try this with taxonomy.

I would suggest making a meta_key "country" with the values.

Then you can query it like in the documentation:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'country', 'meta_value' => 'Israel' ) );
```

Not sure why your taxonomy-query doesnt work, looks fine also, i use it like this for my post-types.

How did you try? Maybe also post the function, where you register the taxonomy, where did you attach it to?

Comment: thanks, I am using a taxonomy because I assign the country to several types of objects (user, post, custom tax, discussions).

I wrote the function in the same place all other funcs are being called from.

Comment: you have to attach your taxonomy to the post_types and object types. That´s the code i would like to see. Can you see your taxonomies in the backend? are you sure the taxonomies work for user? have a look here: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress and here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: Taxonomies are working well for me, i can see it in the backend, I used it many times in and got the custom fields etc. no problem with the tax themselves only I dont know how to query a user by them.
which code do you want to see? I dont mind posting it.

Comment: I probably didn't understand you correctly, I did not know that user saves taxonomy as meta as oppose to post. it worked.

Comment: it´s not what i meant but i am glad it worked, now i also learned something:)  can you pls edit your question with the right code?